# Auto Schema with Nested tables

Tags: google-cloud-data-fusion

I try to get the auto schema from the nested table with Data Fusion, but get this error:

[image]

1) What is the best way to handle nested tables with Data Fusion

2) What is the way to export schema from BigQuery table and use it in Data Fusion?

Answer (score 1):

You are encountering that error due to lack of support for STRUCT type in the BigQuery plugins. This is an improvement to the BigQuery plugin to support the STRUCT type. This is already tracked and prioritized in https://issues.cask.co/browse/CDAP-15256.